# My PATCH request is showing as successful, but nothing is being updated

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Trying to make a simple patch request against a single document, and the request returns

```
{
    "acknowledged": true,
    "modifiedCount": 1,
    "upsertedId": null,
    "upsertedCount": 0,
    "matchedCount": 1
}
```

This is the document I am trying to update

```
{
        "_id": "63843e60079d9cdf9c26505a",
        "name": "AKG_HSD271",
        "image": "images/Products/AKG_hsd271.png",
        "colour": "Black",
        "description": "AKG HSD271 over-ear headset",
        "price": "165.99",
        "startingDateAvailable": "2022-05-10T15:23:28.000Z",
        "type": "Over-Ear",
        "isOnSale": false,
        "stock": 46,
        "EndingDateAvailable": "N/A",
        "manufacturer": "AKG",
        "updatedAt": "2022-12-03T08:48:35.302Z"
}
```

This is the request body I am sending (via Postman)

```
{
    "price": "100.99"
}
```

And here is the code for my route handler

```
router.patch('/Products/:id', (req, res) => {
    console.log('/Products/'+req.params.id);
    const updates = req.body;
    Product.updateOne({_id: ObjectId(req.params.id)}, {$set: updates})
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            res.json(result);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send(err.message);
        });
});
```

Can't for the love of me figure out what is going wrong and why the price field won't change, and can't find any threads that have a suggestion I haven't tried. Any ideas?

Comment: I think the best advise here would be using a debugger.

Comment: According to the response the update was done successfully. Why do you think the document was not updated?

Comment: @nimrod serok, I am attempting to update the price field from 165.99 to 100.99, and every time I try to send the patch request, the field remains the same and does not update. I've tried restarting my node server after each patch but that doesnt do anything

Comment: It is being updated according to the answer. Maybe you are updating a different document than the one you are looking at.

Comment: @nimrod serok I have 20 documents in the collection and I've searched through each one, and non of them update to the new value either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Including the built in json() function in express before my route handlers seemed to do the trick:

```
router.use(express.json())
```

Apparently in express, the body property does not exist on the req object unless you include the json middleware. Hope this helps others.